# Issues passing form data to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I originally had a regular **HTML** form that submitted the data entered through a button, which redirected the user to the **PHP** code page ran the code and everything worked.

Since everything now is confirmed working I need to pass the variables in the form to **PHP** using **Ajax** instead to keep the user on the original page.

All of my code checks out everywhere except for any **Ajax** request I use in the below function. The function correctly grabs all the variables from the form but no matter what form of **Ajax** or `$.post` that I use it fails to pass anything.

I am trying to pass all data to `http://localhost/send-email.php` and respond to the user with a pop up including the echo response from the **PHP** code.

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"  

function capacity(){
  var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var aux = document.getElementById("aux").value;
  var issue = document.getElementById("issue").value;
  var issueid = document.getElementById("issueid").value;
  var reason = document.getElementById("reason").value;
}
```

Like I said I read all documentation on **Ajax** and followed many examples on here but i could not get anything to work.  Any help on what my **Ajax** call should look like is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? Where is your AJAX code? Where is the `$.post` you said you've tried? You've essentially given us nothing to work with.

Comment: I see no AJAX and PHP in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can POST in the backend.

**Method 1 (POST Serialize Array from Form)** - 
[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.post('/send-email.php', $('form').serializeArray(), function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

**Method 2 (Structure Object and POST Object)** - 
[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
var formObject = {
    fullname: $('#fullname').val(),
    time: $('#time').val(),
    aux: $('#aux').val(),
    issue: $('#issue').val(),
    issueid: $('#issueid').val(),
    reason: $('#reason').val()
};

$.post('/send-email.php', formObject, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

**Method 3 (Use AJAX to POST Serialize Array from Form)** - 
[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/send-email.php',
    data: $('form').serializeArray(),
}).done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

**Method 4 (Use AJAX to POST Form Data)** - 
[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - [FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fullname', $('#fullname').val());
formData.append('time', $('#time').val());
formData.append('aux', $('#aux').val());
formData.append('issue', $('#issue').val());
formData.append('issueid', $('#issueid').val());
formData.append('reason', $('#reason').val());

$.ajax({
    url: '/send-email.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Virtually, there are many different methods to achieving what you are attempting.